# Webpack - Devserver not updating babel bundle.js

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I am working through the Lynda tutorial on react - React JS Essential Training. I am stuck on the section where, by using devServer, if I update my index.js file it should automatically update my babel bundle.js file but this not happening.

What I believe is happening is that I have a problem with my webpack.config file because if I update the babel bundle.js file the index.html file updates (but only if I refresh the browser). If I update the index.js file the output in the browser does not update unless I turn off devServer and run babel again.

What am I doing wrong? Here are my files:

**webpack.config**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/assets',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: __dirname + "/dist",
        port: 3333
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const { render } = ReactDOM

render(
    <h1 id='title'
    className='header'
    style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana'}}>
    Ha World
    </h1>,
    document.getElementById('react-container')
    )
```

**bundle.js (babel)**

```
'use strict';

var _ReactDOM = ReactDOM,
    render = _ReactDOM.render;


render(React.createElement(
    'h1',
    { id: 'title',
        className: 'header',
        style: { backgroundColor: 'orange', color: 'white', fontFamily: 'verdana' } },
    'HEY World'
), document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <script src="/react-15.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/react-dom-15.1.0.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World with React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your problem browser not refreshing upon changes in index.js, or that bundle.js in /dist/assets is not updated? Those are two separate things.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. after trying few options I got this working by pointing **publicPath** value in **devServer** options to the location of **output path** in my webpack.config.js file.

my webpack.config.js below

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/sheet.js',
    output : {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'), 
      filename:'rsheet.bundle.js'
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 9000,
        compress: true,
        publicPath: '/dist' // same value as output path 
    },
    plugins: [ ]
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/assets',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: "assets"
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: __dirname + "/dist",
        port: 3333,
        hot: true //trigger hot load.
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() //add hot module replacement plugin.
    ]
}
```

This is the [offical document](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/).

Comment: You should provide explanation on how does your code snippet solve the problem.